# Finding the source of a database update

Tags: mysql, database

I have a mysql database table that is being updated from a different server. I need to fins where the updates are happening from. Other than using a `netstat` to `grep` for the mysql port `3306`, what other options do I have? netstat hasn't helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [general query log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/query-log.html) should be recording the information you're after.